# How to align the div automatically to a new column

Tags: html, css

I have a list of icons to be displayed. I am using the following layout to do this:

```
<div class="icons">
<div class="icon1">
img src="someimage" <p>Some test </p>   
</div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

This is the CSS I am using:

```
.icons{
    margin-top:5px; 
    margin-left:5px;    
    left:0;         
}
.icon1{     
    line-height:15px;
    margin-top:8px;     
    width:75px;
}
```

How do I modify this so that if I add more `div`s with the class `icon1` they will be aligned in a new column when the `max-height` is reached?

Comment: I don't think it's possible by just using html and css

Comment: Raj, there something majorly wrong with your `img` tag there...

Comment: Xenon, i am not able to use img tag in stackoverflow but in my code i have used it properly

Comment: Jack, I tried that too but not working

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether float:left will work. In my experience this causes the div tags to be added side by side and once they reach the end of the parent div the next one will be added to the bottom of the first column. He requires the opposite @Jack

what i suggest is using jquery to check if the height of your div tags are exceeding the parent div. If they are then add a new div and begin appending your image-div tags to the new div with style="float:left". Thus if your initial DOM contains

```
< div class="icons" > < /div >
```

appending one element should change the DOM to

```
<div class="icons" >
    <div class ="column" style="float:left"> 
       <div class="icon1" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

appending another element should change it to

```
<div class="icons" >
    <div class ="column" style="float:left"> 
       <div class="icon1" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
       <div class="icon2" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

appending a third element which exceeds the parent div would change the DOM to this

```
<div class="icons" >
    <div class ="column" style="float:left"> 
       <div class="icon1" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
       <div class="icon2" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="column" style="float:left"> 
       <div class="icon3" > <img src="" height="" width="" /> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice thanks about this but what i am trying is not to use jquery or script is it possible to do with CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS ['multi-columns'](http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/),

[demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3739312)

but it is still a [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), so the [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is still *very* minimal even though you can use vendor prefixes to get it working(although not without some quirks) on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera.